# How do we use Dominated Convergence theorem to prove continuity of average value of f on $B(r,x)$. Folland Real Analysis Lemma 3.16

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Lemma** If $f\in L_{loc}^1, A_rf(x)= \frac
{1}{m(B(r,x))}\int_{B(r,x)}f(y)dy$ is jointly continuous on $r$ and $x$( $r>0, x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Proof: We know that $m(B(r,x))=cr^n$ where $c=m(B(1,0))$ and $m(S(r,x))=0$ where $S(r,x)=\{y:|y-x|=r\}$. Moreover, as $r \rightarrow r_0 $ and $ x\to x_0, \chi_{B(r,x)} \to \chi_{B(r_0,x_0)}$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S(r_0, x_0)$. Hence, $\chi_{B(r,x)} \to \chi_{B(r_0,x_0)}$, a.e and $0\leq \chi_{B(r,x)} \leq \chi_{B(r_0+1,x_0)}$ if $r<r_0+\frac{1}{2}$ and $|x-x_0|<\frac{1}{2}$. By the dominated convergence theorem, it follows that  $\int_{B(r,x)}f(y)dy$ is continuous in $r$ and $x$ and hence so is $A_rf(x)$.

My question is how do we justify the use of Dominated convergence theorem in the proof? I must be missing something silly, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)dy$ is same as $\int \chi _{B(x,r)} (y)  f(y)dy$. The dominating function is $f\chi_{B(r_0+1,x_0)}$ Note that $B(r_0+1,x_0)$  is bounded and $f$ is locally integrable.

Comment: Is there any theorem I am missing?

Comment: It is a simple application of DCT. Do you agree that $f\chi_{B(r_0+1,x_0)}$ is integrable?  @3645

Comment: Yes, how does that implies $\int_{B(r,x)} f(y)dy is continuouos?

Comment: $\chi_{B(r,x))} \to \chi_{B(r_0,x_0)}$ almost everywhere because $\{x: \|x-x_0\|=r\}$ has measure $0$. Take a sequence $r_i \to r$  and a sequence $x_i \to x$ and use sequential definition of continuity.

Comment: Oh! I see thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach $:$

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ and $r_0 > 0.$ Since $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}} (\mathbb R^n)$ it follows that $\int_{B(x_0, r_0 + 1)} |f|\ dm < \infty.$ Define a measure $$\nu (E) : = \int_{E \cap B(x_0,r_0+1)} \left \lvert f \right \rvert\ dm.$$ Then $\nu$ is a finite positive measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to $m.$ So given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $m(E) < \delta$ we have $$\tag{*} \int_{E \cap B(x_0,r_0+1)} \left \lvert f \right \rvert\ dm = \nu (E) < \varepsilon.$$ Choose $0 < \eta < \frac 1 2$ such that whenever $\|x - x_0\| < \eta$ and $\left \lvert r - r_0 \right \rvert < \eta$ we have $m \left (B(x,r) \Delta B(x_0,r_0) \right ) < \delta.$ Now given $y \in B(x,r) \Delta B(x_0,r_0)$ either $y \in B(x_0,r_0)$ or $y \in B(x,r).$ If in addition $\|x - x_0\| < \eta$ and $\left \lvert r - r_0 \right \rvert < \eta$ then the latter case yields $$\begin{aligned} \|y - x_0\| & \leq \|y - x\| + \|x - x_0\| \\ & < r + \eta \\ & \leq \left \lvert r - r_0 \right \rvert + r_0 + \eta \\ & = r_0 + 2 \eta \\ & < r_0 + 1\ \left (\because\ \eta < \frac 1 2 \right ) \end{aligned}$$ Thus $B(x,r) \Delta B(x_0,r_0) \subseteq B(x_0,r_0+1)$ and hence whenever $\|x - x_0\| < \eta$ and $\left \lvert r - r_0 \right \rvert < \eta$ we have $$\begin{aligned} \left \lvert \int_{B(x,r)} f\ dm - \int_{B(x_0,r_0)} f\ dm \right \rvert & = \left \lvert \int_{B(x,r) \setminus B(x_0,r_0)} f\ dm - \int_{B(x_0,r_0) \setminus B(x,r)} f\ dm \right \rvert \\ & \leq \int_{B(x,r) \setminus B(x_0,r_0)} \left \lvert f \right \rvert\ dm + \int_{B(x_0,r_0) \setminus B(x,r)} \left \lvert f \right \rvert\ dm \\ & = \int_{B(x,r) \Delta B(x_0,r_0)} \left \lvert f \right \rvert\ dm \\ & < \varepsilon\ \ (\text{by}\ (*)) \end{aligned}$$ This shows that $$\tag{**} \lim\limits_{(x,r) \to (x_0,r_0)} \int_{B(x,r)} f\ dm = \int_{B(x_0,r_0)} f\ dm.$$

Again whenever $\|x - x_0\| < \eta$ and $\left \lvert r - r_0 \right \rvert < \eta$ we have $B(x,r) \subseteq B(x_0,r_0 + 1)$ and hence $\chi_{B(x,r)} \leq \chi_{B(x_0,r_0+1)}$ and $\chi_{B(x_0,r_0+1)}$ is Lebesgue integrable as $m \left ( 
B(x_0,r_0+1) \right ) < \infty.$ Also as $x \to x_0$ and $r \to r_0$ we have  $\chi_{B(x,r)} \to  \chi_{B(x_0,r_0)}$ pointwise. So by dominated convergence theorem it follows that $$\tag{***}\lim\limits_{(x,r) \to (x_0,r_0)} m \left (B(x,r) \right )  = m \left (B(x_0,r_0) \right )$$ Since non-empty open balls in $\mathbb R^n$ have positive Lebesgue measures so by combining $(**)$ and $(***)$ it follows that $$\lim\limits_{(x,r) \to (x_0,r_0)} \frac {1} {m \left (B(x,r) \right )} \int_{B(x,r)} f\ dm = \frac {1} {m \left (B(x_0,r_0) \right )} \int_{B(x_0,r_0)} f\ dm$$ i.e. $$\lim\limits_{(x,r) \to (x_0,r_0)} A_r f(x) = A_{r_0} f(x_0)$$ which shows that the function $(x,r) \mapsto A_r f(x)$ is jointly continuous at $(x_0,r_0)$ and since $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ and $r_0 \gt 0$ were arbitrarily taken we are done with the proof. $\blacksquare$